# Python script doesn't work on Windows (but works on mac)

Tags: python, python-2.7, httplib2, pygsheets

I run exactly the same script successfully on mac, but it fails on windows server 2012 r2. I wonder what can be a reason and what should i check?
Here is a script:

```
import pygsheets
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='credentials.json')
```

Im getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 2, in <module>
    gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='credentials.json')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py", line 55
2, in authorize
    rclient = Client(oauth=credentials, **client_kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py", line 79
, in __init__
    self._fetch_sheets()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py", line 92
, in _fetch_sheets
    results = self._execute_request(None, request, False)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py", line 41
8, in _execute_request
    response = request.execute()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py", li
ne 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", lin
e 835, in execute
    method=str(self.method), body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", lin
e 162, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\transport.py", l
ine 175, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\transport.py", l
ine 282, in request
    connection_type=connection_type)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1
659, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, metho
d, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1
460, in _request
    _updateCache(headers, response, content, self.cache, cachekey)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 4
74, in _updateCache
    cache.set(cachekey, text)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 7
41, in set
    f = file(cacheFullPath, "wb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\myusername\\appdata\\local\\t
emp\\1fda43ed-78ca-4316-b85c-51e7f359b3cb\\www.googleapis.com,drive,v3,files,inc
ludeTeamDriveItems=false&pageSize=500&fields=files%28id%2C+name%29&corpora=user&
supportsTeamDrives=false&q=mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.spreadshe
et%,5a24ad0f84d69be2396dd368422a2b6c'
```

Apparentely this folder is empty:

```
c:\\users\\myusername\\appdata\\local\\temp\\1fda43ed-78ca-4316-b85c-51e7f359b3cb
```

I wonder if it is something to do with access level to c:\ProgramData on windows and if so how can i fix that?
I also updated conda and pygsheets on both machines.

Comment: Did u try running the script as administrator in windows?

Comment: Whatever `cacheFullPath` is, it's apparently populated with something which isn't a valid file name at all. What's in `credentials.json`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a known bug in pygsheets, install from github to get the fix. Or as a workaround, you can turn cache off.

```
import pygsheets
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='credentials.json', no_cache=True)
```