# Pygsheets .updated returns "File not found"

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

I am trying to check the date of the latest modification to a google sheet using [*pygsheets 1.1.4*](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets), [*google-api-python-client 1.6.7*](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client), and *Python 3.6.3* on Windows 10.

I can authenticate, view, and edit spreadsheet contents, but when I try to get the last-modified date:

```
my_client = pygsheets.authorize(service_file=secret_service_acct_file)
my_worksheet = my_client.open_by_key(my_key)
last_updated = my_worksheet.updated
```

I instead get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#77>", line 1, in <module>
    my_worksheet.updated
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\spreadsheet.py", line 90, in updated
    response = self.client._execute_request(self.id, request, False)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py", line 459, in _execute_request
    response = request.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 840, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{API_KEY}?fields=modifiedTime&supportsTeamDrives=false&alt=json returned "File not found: {API_KEY}.">
```

This, to me, indicates that the file is not found. I would expect other read/write operations to fail if the authorization or the connection had some issue. I have tried opening the spreadsheet with `open_by_url()` instead, but received the same results.

I am using *google-api-python-client v1.6.7* and *pygsheets v1.1.4*, freshly installed from GitHub. I have tried running in "administrator" mode and running with `no_cache=True`, as per suggestions in other [pygsheets](/questions/tagged/pygsheets) questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397104/python-script-doesnt-work-on-windows-but-works-on-mac), to no avail.

I was using *gspread 0.6.2* until I realized I would eventually need "Team Drive" support. *gspread 3.0.0* claims to offer "Team Drive" support, but also deprecated the `.updated` attribute that I need.

How can I get my latest `modifiedTime` with pygsheets, or should I be using a different library altogether?

edit: I noticed that pygsheets uses the v3 Sheets API for the attribute I'm trying to call, and [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42687272/9802540) describes the removal of "file oriented" options between the v3 Sheets API and the v4 Sheets API, but [the migration guide from google](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration) doesn't seem to have any hints for my use case.

Comment: are you able to do make other requests? like `my_worksheet.sheet1.update_value('A1',"test")` ? I am unabel to reproduce your error.

Comment: If your sheet is in a team drive you would need to turn on teamdirve. Its not turned on by default.

Comment: Pygsheets uses Sheets API from Google. You can try if the file really exist in the [spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) Try-it.

Comment: @noogui Yes, I can make updates using the Python sample for the v4 Sheets API on that page, so I believe that my file exists.

Comment: Thanks, @nithin for prompting me to double check the teamdrive settings. Someone on the team did move the file into teamdrives without my knowledge, and setting enableTeamDriveSupport=True resolved my issue.